# Sending binary data from browser

Tags: google-chrome, binary, websocket, send, arraybuffer

I wanted to know what I must do for sending data in binary type from client to server?

I am using Chrome 14, and when I send an `ArrayBuffer` in the client application, I receive a frame with the `opcode` set to `opText` and a string as frame data  "[object ArrayBuffer]"` in the server application.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should download the latest nightly build since it has only been implemented in Chrome 16 (currently that's the developer channel). You could also download Chrome Canary.

Currently, in Chrome 14/15, you can only send strings and as such, an `ArrayBuffer` is converted to a string: `someArrayBuffer.toString() === "[object ArrayBuffer]"`.

It has been implemented in [WebKit revision `94482`](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/94482), but Chrome 14 (build 835) only includes up to [WebKit revision `91698`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/branches/835/src/DEPS?revision=98687&view=markup).